# Azure DevOps Build Error - Java Application Ant Build in Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, ant

[1]I am building java application using ANT agent task ( ANT Build ). But receiving this attached error.

Build process keep waiting for below parameters

"
get-ruleset:
[input] ruleset name:
"

( But I can able to build basic application and created jar )

Note: In Project folder location "ruleset.xml" and "satbuild.xml" both files are available

Not able to follow on this please let me know how to resolved this build issue[enter image description here][2]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVy7X.png               [Error]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GPfO.png [Pipeline]

Comment: can you share your pipeline definition, to see what exactly happens in that step?

Comment: Updated pipelin detail and error. Please check Thank you [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVy7X.png [Error] [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GPfO.png [Pipeline]